# how to run this.setState function here

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i can't run this.setState in line 132

[image: error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an arrow syntax for the handler of `reader.onloaded`.

```
reader.onloaded = () => {
  preview.src = reader.result
  this.setState(...)
}
```

The reason is because `function` has its own `this` thus will prevent you from accessing `React.Component`'s `this`.

A method created with an arrow syntax doesn't create its own `this`. Or you can also bind `this` to the function.

```
reader.onloaded = (function() {
  preview.src = reader.result
  this.setState(...)
}).bind(this)
```

, which works but well you can decide whether to use it or not

Answer (score 0):

If you convert your function to an arrow function it should work.

```
reader.onLoadEnd = () => {
     this.setState({state:state})
}
```